# How can I get the combined query for two hasManyThrough

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have two relationships on the users' table:

```
public function tokens_records()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough(Record::class, Token::class);
}
```

and

```
public function websites_records()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough(Record::class, Website::class);
}
```

How can I merge both queries into one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the records for both relationships, this is gonna work:

```php
class Entity extends Model
{
    public function tokens_records()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Record::class, Token::class);
    }

    public function websites_records()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Record::class, Website::class);
    }
}

$records = $entity->tokens_records
    ->merge($entity->websites_records);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this loads the data before returning the result. I am looking for a way to return a relationship instance